# How to count number of times a text appeared in multiple cells using python

Tags: python, cloud, nltk

I want to figure out a way by which I could count number of times a similar word have appeared in multiple rows. For example, `Street` have appeared, `Carla` have appeared twice. (* Note --> There are many such rows wherein I am not sure which word is common)

| Description |
| --- |
| Street 29 euro |
| Street 31 USD |
| Carla xyz 45 output |
| Street 345 tmd |
| Carla asb 6789 tim |

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what format your data is in but lets assume its a pandas DataFrame.

First convert to a list:

```
rows = df["Description"]
```

Create a large list as a container for all words:

```
large_list = []
```

Iterate over the rows, split each row by whitespaces and append the list of words in this row to the large list:

```
for row in rows:
    large_list += row.split()
```

Count how often each element (word) in the list occurs:

```
import collections
counts = collections.Counter(large_list)
print(counts)
```

You might want to add filters such as a word can only contain of letters (and not e.g. numbers), stopword filtering etc..